Marketing Cloud - iOS app Push notificiation badge value count always 1
We are using Marketing Cloud SDK 8.1.2 for sending push notifications for iOS app.
In the notification payload the badge value is always 1 and does not increase when there are more number of notifications.
How to manage the badge count when there are more number of notifications. Is there a way to calculate badge value when a push is sent through marketing cloud.

Badge count increases for inbox + alert push notifications. Count does not increase for normal push notifications.
Please see https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/application-badging/application-badging.html
Thanks,
Prakashini
